# Unwrapping secrete key without exposing original key?

Tags: pkcs11

I am trying to unwrap a secret key (AES/DES) using Java APIs and SunPKCS11. Problem is that it reveals the value of an unwrapped key (out of HSM) in the key object. Here is the code:

```
Key privateKey = keyStore.getKey("MyKeyId", keyStorePassword);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA", "SunPKCS11-Safenet");
cipher.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, privateKey);
// The unwrapped key is visible in below line in unwrappedKey object
Key unwrappedKey = cipher.unwrap(wrappedKey, "AES", Cipher.SECRET_KEY);
```

How can I tell the code to not to reveal the unwrapped key?

Do I have to add something in PKCS11 cfg file? I tried below in cfg file but doesn't help:

```
attributes(*,CKO_SECRET_KEY,*) = {
CKA_SENSITIVE=true
}
```

Also asked the same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52220368/unwrap-secrete-key-reveals-actual-key but I have got no response.

Comment: Hi, snesh, and welcome to Cryptography Stack Exchange. Unfortunately, questions about how to use a specific cryptographic library are generally [off-topic](/help/on-topic) here. Such questions are better suited for [SO]. (In this case, it looks like you've [already asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52220368) there as well. Please note in the future that asking the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites at the same time is also not recommended. At the very least, if you decide to do so, you should clearly note it in your question and link the questions together.)

Comment: Thank you for informing IImari. BTW, I have added reference to already asked question.